# How can I vertically and horizontally center a div within a larger div?

Tags: html, css

[How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div) I managed to center horizontally using styling from the accepted answer. How can I also center it vertically? The inner div is of an unknown height.

Comment: Is javascript an option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
  <style>
    .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to see it */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cool technique for centering a box both vertically and horizontally :

### The outher container

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`
- should have `text-align: center;`

### The content box

- should have `display: inline-block;`
- should re-adjust the horizontal text-alignment to eg. `text-align: left;` or `text-align: right;`, unless you want text to be centered

The elegance of this technique, is that **you can add your content to the content box without worrying about its height or width!**

Just add your content to the content box.

### Demo

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* This could be ANY width */
    height: 100%; /* This could be ANY height */
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        <p>You can put anything here</p>
        <p>Yes, really anything!</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/621/)!