# How to make div horizontally and vertically centered without scripting?

Tags: css, html

How to make div horizontally and vertically centered without scripting?
Only on CSS and HTML5?

```
<div id="center"></div>

#center{width:500px; height:300px;}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the text within this div or the div itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489781/how-can-i-vertically-and-horizontally-center-a-div-within-a-larger-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed size :

```
#center{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-150px 0 0 -250px;
}
```

If you want to resize your `div` with the screen you can use [this technique](http://matthecat.com/blog-lire-2-centrer-une-image-a-l-ecran.html) which works for `div` too.

Comment: you're welcome ^^ so you can check the mark at the side of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CSS 3 box-align?

```
#center {
    box-align: center;
}
```

Find more information here: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

Comment: maybe you need to add the vendor specific prefixes:
*-moz-box-align: center;* for Firefox or *-webkit-box-align: center;* for Safari & Chrome

Comment: If you don't want to use cutting-edge CSS 3 syntax you could have a look at http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 1):

```
body, html {height:100%}
.mydiv {width:300px; height:300px; margin:auto; background:#FF0000}
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><div class="mydiv"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just Add this things: 
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right: auto ;

so, Your center should be like this:

```
#center
{width:500px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right: auto ;
}
```